# Response any web page in the internet from a PHP file

Tags: php

How can I create a simple PHP file, which will retrieve the HTML and the Headers of any web page in the internet, change images/resources url to their full url (for example: image.gif to http://www.google.com/image.gif), and then response it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'response it'?

Comment: print it's content and headers...

Comment: What do you mean change the image URL to the full URL? For example, if the image URL was image.gif, how would it know that the domain was google.com? All I can think of is changing the URL to its canonical form, i.e. google.com/image.gif => http://www.google.com/image.gif

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first of all to get the headers use the PHP [get_headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.example.com/";
$headers = get_headers($url, true);

?>
```

Then read the content of the page into a variable.

```
<?php

$handle = fopen($url, r);
$content = '';
while(! feof($handle)) {
    $text .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

You then need to run through the content looking for resources and pre-pending the url to get the absolute path to the resource if it isn't already an absolute path. The following regex example will work on src attributes (e.g. images and javascript) and should give you a starting point to look at other resources such as CSS which uses href="". This regex won't match if a : is in the source a good indicator that it contains http:// and is therefore an absolute path. PLEASE NOTE this is by no means perfect and won't account for all sorts of weird and wonderful resource locations but it's a good start.

```
<?php

$pattern = '@src="([0-9A-Za-z-_/\.])+"@';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $src = str_replace('src="', '', $match);
    $text = str_replace($match, 'src="' . $url . $src, $text);
}

print($text);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$file = "http://www.somesite/somepage";
$handle = fopen($file, "rb");
$text = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $text .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
print($text);
?>
```

Comment: Ya, right, and no headers now. I started to write before question update.

Comment: Thanks, but, but how can I change the image urls?

Comment: I'm not very good with regexes, I think you can search for <img src="{url}" in text and then replace it with <img src="{site}{url}"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a PHP Proxy script. There are several on the internet - [this is one](http://code.google.com/p/php-web-proxy/) I created (although don't have time to fix bugs at the moment).

I would recommend using one which is already created over one which you've written yourself, as it's not a trivial thing to do (there are better scripts than mine available as well).